# Div isn't stretching to 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css

I'm designing my CSS layout, but can't get the div to stretch to 100% of the height of the parent.

I have a menu bar that takes up the top 13.714vh of the screen. Then I have a main div that I want to take up the remainder of the screen height which I did with height: 100%. bottom-container takes up the bottom 38.2% of the vertical space available in main, and I want speech-bubble to take up the remaining 61.8% of the vertical space in main.

For some reason though, there's a huge white container in the middle of the screen, and speech-bubble isn't taking up the remaining space because of it. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Is there a problem with my HTML or did I make an error in the CSS?

Here's the code pen:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/NWjKwxE

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-bar {
  height: 13.714vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: darkblue;
  top: 0%;
}

.main {
  background: black;
  grid-template-rows: 61.8% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
}

.speech-bubble {
  grid-row: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  height: 97%;
  width: 97%;
  border-radius: 4em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -4em;
  margin-bottom: -4em;
}

.email-container {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.question-text {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.bottom-container {
  grid-row: 2;
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  height: 38.2%;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_bar" , class="menu-bar"></div>
<div id="main" , class="main">
  <div id="speech_bubble" , class="speech-bubble">
    <div id="email_container" class="email-container">
      <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
      <button id="submit_email_btn" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div id="question_text" class="question-text">Question</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom_container" , class="bottom-container">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle and add the demo here..

Comment: I have a code pen I meant to include, just edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want anything like this? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMnLq.png).

If so, making your `.menu-bar` as `position: relative` and modifying your `.main` class styles as follows will work:

```
.main {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Also, you may add `margin: auto` in your speech-bubble class to align it to center.

Answer (score 0):

Your main tag is not taking full height as your html and body tags are not taking the full height.
Always remember that block elements can stretch maximum to their's parent's height, hence you need to give html and body tag height of 100%.
I have added the additional css below.

```
html, body { height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you want thing like this

```
      * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100vh;
      }
      .menu-bar {
      height: 13.714vh;
      background-color: tomato;
      color: #fff
      }
      .main {
      background: black;
      padding: 1.5%;
      flex: 1
      }
      .speech-bubble {
      background-color: orange;
      border-radius: 4em;
      height: 95%;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      }
      .speech-bubble:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 4em solid transparent;
      border-top-color: white;
      border-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: -4em;
      margin-bottom: -4em;
      }
      .email-container {
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      }
      .question-text {
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center
      }
      .bottom-container {
      height: 70px;
      background-color: lightseagreen;
      }
```